# Styled components babel plugin in create-react-app with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, styled-components

Can I use the styled components babel plugin in a create-react-app application that uses TypeScript?

I have read in the docs that there is a "macro [that] incorporates all the functionality of [the] babel plugin while allowing the unejected tooling to handle the Babel part of the build process."

I have tried:

```
npm install babel-plugin-macros
```

and

```
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
const Div = styled.div`
`;
```

On `npm run start` in the console I get

```
Compiled with warnings.

./node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js
62:46-53 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
8:17-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

When visiting the application in the browser I get

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_styled_components_macro__.a.div is not a function
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I did not manage to fix this

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same issue. I was trying to run a `tsc -b -w` (watch) over a monorepo while at the same time running a `react-scripts start` in a `create-react-app` project so I could watch projects and build upstream ones if they changed.

I eventually realized that the reason this wasn't working was because I had the styled components defined in a `.ts` file instead of a `.tsx` file, for example a `Menu.styles.ts` file. When I renamed it to `Menu.styles.tsx` the concurrent watch + `start` worked consistently.

Hope this helps someone.